# How can I automatically update hundreds of T-SQL stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, automation

I want to add the word `commit` after the words `@p_TEXT = @temp;` in hundreds of T-SQL stored procedures

What I came up with is to run the following code, select all rows with the mouse, copy and then execute

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        REPLACE(REPLACE(TEXT, 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE'), '@p_TEXT = @temp;', '@p_TEXT = @temp;commit;')
        ,CHAR(10), 'GO')
FROM sys.procedures p
JOIN sys.syscomments s ON p.object_id = s.id
WHERE TEXT LIKE '%@p_TEXT%' 
  AND LEN(text) < 4000
```

I had to add a condition `LEN(text) < 4000` because otherwise I would lose any text after 4000 characters. These are only a few, so I could do these manually.

The main problem is that if there are any comments in the stored procedure, then since the stored procedure is retrieved from the database as a single line, *everything* after the initial comment is treated as a comment.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE example @param1 INT ,@param2 -- comment   ,@param3 ,@P_Result INT OUTPUT  AS
```

Any ideas of either improving this code or doing it differently?

Comment: Why are you using [`syscomments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscomments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? That's for SQL Server 2000 databases. Are you really still using SQL Server 2000?

Comment: *"then since the stored procedure is retrieved from the database as a single line"* I won't comment for `syscomments`, but that statement is certainly not true in [`sys.sql_modules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: If you have your database in version control then you can use a find and replace on the project (although this might inadvertently make changes to functions, so you may have to open all procedures and find and replace in all open documents). You can then deploy your project to the target database. This has the added benefit of being able to rollback if you find that a find and replace across hundreds of procedures in bulk doesn't work as expected. If you don't have your database in version control then it's probably a good idea to add it to version control anyway.

Comment: I would point out though that this is quite an unusual ask and if you have 100s of stored procedures that begin transactions and don't currently commit them, and also all are so structured that such a generic find and replace will work, then that is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: @Thom A - I am using SQL Server Azure. I changed to `sys.sql_modules` as you suggested, but am still experiencing the same problem. If one does `select top  1  s.definition from sys.procedures p join sys.sql_modules s on p.object_id = s.object_id` and then copies and pastes, then it appears to be one line.  So I am not understanding something!

Comment: Have you enabled retain CR/LF on copy in SSMS? Copying the data when it's stripping them before you copy it isn't a good indicator that it doesn't have line breaks. I can guarantee you that `sys.sql_modules` has details of line breaks.

Comment: @GarethD - I hear that it sounds like a code smell! However (in short) all the procedures do commit the transactions, but they have an identical TRY CATCH which calls an error routine which records the error in the database. This needs to be committed in the calling procedure and not in the nested procedure. The problem originated after automatic migration from Oracle.

Comment: @Thom A. I feel a bit silly but that works great. Thank you.  If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since the stored procedure is retrieved from the database as a single line

This is caused by having "Retain CR/LF" switched off in SSMS.

Having said that, you can actually make all the modifications in one go in code, by using a cursor.

- Don't use `sys.syscomments` it's deprecated. Use `sys.sql_modules` instead.
- `GO` is not necessary (and doesn't work) when using `EXEC`. Use separate batches instead.
- Note that this is going to break if any of your procedures do not have the exact text `CREATE PROCEDURE`

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @crsr CURSOR;

SET @crsr = CURSOR FOR
SELECT
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      s.definition,
      'CREATE PROCEDURE',
      'ALTER PROCEDURE'
    ),
    '@p_TEXT = @temp;',
    '@p_TEXT = @temp;
commit;')
FROM sys.procedures p
JOIN sys.sql_modules s ON p.object_id = s.object_id
WHERE s.definition LIKE '%@p_TEXT%';

OPEN @crsr;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @crsr INTO @sql;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK;

    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZQ16kB9W)